# how can I approach this question better

Tags: discussion

I have a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670072/are-there-examples-of-companies-using-differential-software-testing-in-practice and I'm looking for more information.  Someone commented that this may be too opinion based - maybe should be moved to programmers.stackexchange.

I'm wondering if there is a way to approach this question better.  I think in general it's a valuable question that others may have - but I haven't found more information about differential testing outside of the papers listed.  I'm trying to get real tips or advice about the approach.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm trying to get real tips or advice about the approach.

And that's not the type of question that we want here on SO (or programmers for that matter; the person who suggested you go there was wrong to do so).

Comment: So what would be an example or direction of a question that would be similar to this - but fit within what SO is trying to do.  I'm trying to solve a problem of how to simplify getting starting with regression testing - this seems like a promising approach, but I don't know.  There are plenty of question on SO that are not very different from this question, at least in spirit.

Comment: @Yehosef The direction of your question is what is the problem.  You're trying to hold an open ended discussion.  SO is for specific, answerable programming problems, not open ended discussions.  Since the core concept is the problem, changing the question while maintaining that core concept wouldn't make it any more acceptable.

Comment: I'm trying to bootstrap the answers.. but I can zoom out - "What is differential software testing and what are examples of its use?"  Would that be more in line?

Comment: @Yehosef No, that would be Too Broad.

Comment: I'm trying to find out more information about a specific approach to testing - how is this any less broad than http://stackoverflow.com/q/520064 ?

Comment: There are plenty of other questions that are not entirely different from mine  http://stackoverflow.com/q/504823/214545, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3639849/214545, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17168707/214545

Comment: @Yehosef Thanks for pointing out some questions that merit closure.  Note that the existence of other questions meriting closure, even ones that aren't currently closed, doesn't mean it that questions are on topic or that it's okay for you to ask them.  You can find thousands upon thousands of questions that should be closed but haven't been.  Sadly, there just aren't enough people curating content to close all of it.

Comment: The unfortunate part about all this is that many time those types of questions are really useful and exactly what I need and am looking for as a developer.  It's sad that this is not the "vision" of SE and we'd have to resort Quora to ask the questions we need answers to.

Comment: @Yehosef SE isn't meant to be everything to everyone.  It's designed to support a very small subset of questions extremely effectively, rather than trying to support any type of possible question very poorly (like, say, Quora or yahoo answers).  The quality on SE comes from, in no small part, from limiting the scope of content it supports.